# Can't seem to disable auto login on Kali Linux live USB flash drive

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have a Kali Linux live USB flash drive with persistent encrypted volume, with the latest update. Everything is fine, except when I try to disable auto login, I can't seem to get it work.

I switched from LightDM to SDDM. I tried everything from [this  article](https://techpiezo.com/linux/enable-or-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-20-04/) and other similar Google results.

- I confirmed `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` is SDDM.
- I edited `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf` to comment out the autologin section.
- I even edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to comment out auto login.
- I even created `/etc/sddm.conf.d/autologin.conf` with the autologin commented out.

When I boot up, after I type in the password for encrypted volume, it goes straight to Plasma loading.

I can log out of the "kali" user and I will get a login screen. But I want to stop auto login.

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal:

```
echo 'LIVE_CONFIG_NOAUTOLOGIN="true"' | sudo tee -a /etc/live/config.conf
```

and reboot

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.  Still boots right into the kali user.  I checked and the value is set in /etc/live/config.conf.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct file has changed. Am on Kali Live 2022.1 (kali-rolling) and the file is `/etc/live/config.conf.d/kali.conf` thus to modify and prevent autologin do as follows;

```
echo 'LIVE_CONFIG_NOAUTOLOGIN="true"' | sudo tee -a /etc/live/config.conf.d/kali.conf
```